# wipe gesture windows mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, .net-cf-3.5

I want to use **gestures** on a windows mobile phone. For example (using .net cf 3.5) to wipe from left to right on the touchscreen over a form or something and switch to next form and of course back.

I know its not that difficult to create it on my own, but maybe someone did that before. Specially if there are some extra gestures like circles and so on...

Thank you for your help.

Greetings Karl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article explains pretty well how to use gestures:

[Optimizing Screen Area Using Mouse Gestures](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21916/Optimizing-Screen-Area-Using-Mouse-Gestures)

Also check this MSDN sample code:

[Windows Mobile Managed Gestures Sample](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/gestureswm/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3438)

Comment: That's for Windows Phone, not Windows Mobile and there is a *huge* difference between the two.

Comment: @ctacke: sorry, my bad; I changed to a suitable answer :)